# Can you have a method call inside of an array declaration?

Tags: java, arrays

Quick question, is it possible in Java to call a method inside an array declaration? For example:

I have this method:

```
public int countCarsByYear(int year) { /*not shown*/ }
```

That returns the number of cars that have a year attribute that matches the given year.

Now I need to implement this method:

```
public int[][] findAllYear(int year) { /*not shown*/ }
```

That returns an int matrix, where each row is an array of 2 coordinates to the Car object in a Car matrix that matches the given year.

So would I be able to start off my code using this:

```
int[][] carsInYear = new int[countCarsByYear(year)][2];
```

Or would I need to have a separate variable equal to *countCarsByYear(year)* and pass that in?

Comment: why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Because it's being written in paper and pen. If I start using an IDE, I would have to implement everything I've already written into there, which would take a while.

Comment: Here is a hint: try using ideone.com

Comment: Refer to the [language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6). You can use any expression with`int` type.

Comment: Umm, "it's being written in paper and pen. If I start using an IDE, I would have to implement everything I've already written" is actually the right way to go. In decades of computer programming I've met only one person who could write code without using a compiler that worked for someone who did use a compiler. Your pen and paper won't give you nearly the help that an IDE and a compiler will, especially when you're new. Bite the bullet. Don't be lazy. And don't ask questions you can answer in two minutes using a compiler yourself.

Comment: The AP Computer Science course requires all free response answers to be handwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should try it yourself, but here you go

```
    static int [] arr = new int [getcount ()];
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        System.out.println(arr.length);
    }

    private static int getcount() {
        return 7;
    }
```

**output**

`7`